# Adding Geolocation Google Map Failed

Tags: html, google-maps, geolocation

I am still very new to HTML5 but I am trying to add a Google Map with Geolocation and a few points that people can find. When I refresh the page after submitting the code it doesn't appear. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong or correct the code?

The site isn't complex, here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand active" href="index.html">Smart Homes<span class="sr-only"></span></a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="Testimonial.html">Testimonials<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Thermostat<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="MobileThermostat.html">Mobile Thermostat</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Installation.html">Installation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Ordering Info<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">How To Order/Cost</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">New Letter Registration</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Energy Saving <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                            <li><a href="Tips.html">Energy Tips</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Tutorial.html">Take A Tour</a></li>


                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="RegisterWithSmartHomes.html">Create An Account</a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Find Our Products Nearby </h1>
            <h2>Use Our Map</h2>
            <p>
                Use our map below to find a location near you.

            </p>


        </div>

   <div>
    <script>


function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 13
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}

    </script>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>Mobile Thermostat</h2>
                <p>Learn more about the mobile thermostat by following this link.  </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="MobileThermostat.html" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>Ordering and Cost</h2>
                <p>Get cost and ordering information here.  You'll be surprised and how economical the Smart Homes Mobile Thermostat system is, and how much it will save you over time. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>Customer Testimonials</h2>
                <p>Find out how our customers feel about their decision to buy our system, and how it has improved their lives, reduced costs, providing comfort and convenience.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="Testimonial.html" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Smart Homes Inc. 2015</p>
        </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/playVidoeChosen.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    <script>
        (function (b, o, i, l, e, r) {
            b.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l; b[l] || (b[l] =
            function () { (b[l].q = b[l].q || []).push(arguments) }); b[l].l = +new Date;
            e = o.createElement(i); r = o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e, r)
        }(window, document, 'script', 'ga'));
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X'); ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This could help to get started [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: I did review that page, but I am still a bit clueless on where I am going wrong. The code looks right to me.

Comment: Since you are using geolocation api from google you may try this tut [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-use-geolocation-api-with-google-maps).

Answer (score 0):

did you add a div with an id 'map' to your html code? Because I did not find a div with id 'map' in your code. Maybe you need to add the following code.

```
<div id="map"></div>
```